# Meaning of the word dom.

Tags: measure-theory, notation

Let X be a set and $\sum$ a $\sigma$ algebra of subsets of X. Let f and g be real valued functions defined on domains :

dom $f$ and dom $g$ $\subseteq X$.

If $f$ and $g$ are measurable , so is $f+g$ where $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ for $x \in$dom$f \cap $ dom$g$

What does dom mean in this context?

What are dom $f$ and dom $g$? And why are they so significant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

> $f(x)=\frac1x$ is differentiable with $f'(x)=-\frac1{x^2}$

is not precise, it has a problem. But the statement

> $f(x)=\frac1x$ is differentiable on its domain, $dom{f}=\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ with $f'(x)=-\frac1{x^2}$

is correct. Similarly (you can construct many, many examples) in your case consider the statements:

> Let $f(x)=\frac1x$ and $g(x)=x$, so $f(x)+g(x)=x+\frac1x$

So, $g(0)=0$ but what is $(f+g)(0)$? It is not defined. So, improve (considerably) the previous statement as

> Let $f(x)=\frac1x$ for any $x$ except $x=0$ (domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and $g(x)=x$ for any $x$ (domain of $g$ is $\mathbb R$), so $(f+g)(x)=x+\frac1x$ for any $x$ except $x=0$.

The main problem is that outside the domain of the function, statements about the function *do not make sense*.

Comment: So the use of the word dom as in dom f means that it will always work on dom f?

Comment: Yes, $dom f$ is the domain of $f$ and is important to determine it before making any statement about $f$. For example $dom f=[0,1]$ or $dom f=(-\infty,0) \cup (0, +\infty)$ or $dom f=\mathbb R$ etc.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, than you.

Comment: In my question above, dom f and dom g are not specified though.

Comment: Yes, in your question it is a general statement. In my answer there are examples.

Comment: I understand now

Answer (score 5):

dom is short for *domain* (of a function).

Answer (score 1):

Dom means domain. A function may not be defined on all of $X$ but only on a subset.